# How does current flow through a capacitor?

Tags: electricity

I just want to know how charge flows through the empty space between the parallel plates of a capacitor?

Comment: Charge does not flow through the empty space between the plats.
 There is, however, what we call a [displacement current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current) which maintains the continuity of current/

Answer (score 3):

a capacitor consists of two conducting plates facing each other across a narrow gap, with wires connected to each plate. imagine we send a burst of electrons into the wire leading to the plate on the left. As they flow into the plate, they assert an electrostatic field in the gap between the two plates which repels any loose electrons on the plate on the right, and those electrons then flow out of the plate and out the wire. Once the field's strength is no longer changing in time, no more electrons get pushed out of the plate and the current dies out. In this way, a capacitor supports the transmittal of brief pulses of current in response to applied voltages which are varying in time. this means that a capacitor is a conductor for rapidly-varying AC signals, while it is a complete block to DC (because there is no physical connection between the two plates).

Comment: could whoever downvoted this answer correct it if you think it is wrong or inaccurate?